# when a button will clicked an input field will auto focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic

see the below fiddle link. after clicking on green button of "phone 1" section I need to focus the input with green button of "phone 2" section. is it possible? help me.

[see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o6h1L9j8/)

### JS

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {

        var addFormGroup = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
            var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');
            var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();
            $formGroup.find('input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', 'true')

            $(this).toggleClass('btn-success btn-add btn-danger btn-remove').html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>');

            $formGroupClone.find('input').val('');
            $formGroupClone.find('.concept').text('Phone');
            $formGroupClone.insertAfter($formGroup);

            var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
            if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') <= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
                $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        };

        var removeFormGroup = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
            var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');

            var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
            if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') >= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
                $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', false);
            }

            $formGroup.remove();
        };

        var selectFormGroup = function (event) {
            // event.preventDefault();

            // var $selectGroup = $(this).closest('.input-group-select');
            // var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
            // var concept = $(this).text();

            // $selectGroup.find('.concept').text(concept);
            // $selectGroup.find('.input-group-select-val').val(param);



        }

        var countFormGroup = function ($form) {
            return $form.find('.form-group').length;
        };

        $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', addFormGroup);
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', removeFormGroup);
        $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', selectFormGroup);

    });
})(jQuery);
```

### HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <div style="padding-left:17px; padding-right:17px;">
        <label>phone 1</label>
        <div class="form-group multiple-form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="contacts['value'][]" class="form-control" placeholder="Add email address" style="border-radius:0;"> <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add" style="border-radius:0;">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </span>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background:#fff;">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label style="padding:0; width:100%; font-size:16px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="cell_no">Mobile</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background:#fff;">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label style="padding:0; width:100%; font-size:16px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="cell_no">Phone</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background:#fff;">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label style="padding:0; width:100%; font-size:16px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="cell_no">Work</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left:17px; padding-right:17px;">
        <label>phone 2</label>
        <div class="form-group multiple-form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="contacts['value'][]" class="form-control" placeholder="Add email address" style="border-radius:0;"> <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add" style="border-radius:0;">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </span>

            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background:#fff;">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label style="padding:0; width:100%; font-size:16px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="cell_no">Mobile</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background:#fff;">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label style="padding:0; width:100%; font-size:16px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="cell_no">Phone</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4" style="background:#fff;">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label style="padding:0; width:100%; font-size:16px;">
                            <input type="radio" name="cell_no">Work</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What Fiddle? Can you please make your questions a bit more descriptive.

Comment: use the focus() method

Comment: Don't try to hack around the question limitation that prevents you from posting a fiddle link without code please.  Instead, add some relevant code to the question to help explain your situation and include the fiddle link normally.  There is a good reason the system stops you from trying to do this.  Listen to the warnings and you'll have a much better experience on SO.

Comment: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/o6h1L9j8/)

Comment: @sohag513 Please update your question with your code and the jsfiddle link.

Comment: I'd updated the question.

Comment: @admdrew question updated with jsfiddle link

Comment: @sohag513 I rolled back your edit, as Kyle Needham's edit included the code, **which is required when using JSFiddle links**, as it very clearly says when editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuerys focus() method. Like this:

```
$formGroupClone.find('input[type=text]').focus()
```

You will have to add this line in **addFormGroup**

```
var addFormGroup = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
        var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-group');
        var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();
        $formGroup.find('input[type=radio]').attr('disabled','true')

        $(this).toggleClass('btn-success btn-add btn-danger btn-remove').html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>');

        $formGroupClone.find('input').val('');
        $formGroupClone.find('.concept').text('Phone');
        $formGroupClone.insertAfter($formGroup);
        $formGroupClone.find('input[type=text]').focus()

        var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
        if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') <= countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
            $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    };
```

jsfiddle is also updated http://jsfiddle.net/o6h1L9j8/5/

Comment: thanks @Morten OC it's working. but I tried this way before. any way thanks again.